# USB to Serial RS232 - device setup correctly but software cannot open port?

Tags: windows-10, 64-bit, rs232, com

USB to serial set up correctly with drivers and device manager states "The device is working properly" and assigned to COM2, but no software seems to be able to detect or use COM2.

cmd mode gives only COM1 (internal to motherboard)
putty gives "Unable to open connection to COM2. Unable to open serial port"
The intended use software simply gives nothing.

The same behaviour for two different USB to serial adaptors (FTDI and Prolific).

Checking for processes using the service assigned to the COM port also shows nothing.

Comment: Check device manager to see if it even shows up there.

Comment: Usb COM port adaptors often increment port numbers when you change the adaptor or even just the USB port it is plugged into. As Pylsa mentions you will need to show and verify the the correct port is being used.

Answer (score 1):

Problem was solved by changing USB ports to front of PC from back.

Suspected reasons for this are that too much power was being drawn by other attachments to the rear USB controller for the USB to serial to function correctly.